# How to install opengl for this to run

Tags: user-interface, go, opengl, fyne

I am trying following simple code to create a GUI using [Fyne](https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne) package:

```
// from: https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne
package main
import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
)
func main() {
    app := app.New()
    w := app.NewWindow("Hello")
    w.SetContent(widget.NewVBox(
        widget.NewLabel("Hello Fyne!"),
        widget.NewButton("Quit", func() {
            app.Quit()
        }),
    ))
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

It compiles and builds executable file without any error or even warning, but on trying to run it gives following error:

```
I:\>rnfynetest
2019/08/25 12:37:18 Fyne error:  failed to initialise OpenGL
2019/08/25 12:37:18   Cause: glBeginConditionalRender
2019/08/25 12:37:18   At: C:/Users/ABCD/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/gl/window.go:1007
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x2c pc=0x572afd]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/gl.(*window).SetContent(0x0, 0x8fc5e0, 0x1386e0c0)
        C:/Users/ABCD/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/gl/window.go:361 +0x1d
main.main()
        I:/rnfynetest.go:10 +0x1ce
```

As given on [Fyne homepage](https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne) I need to install OpenGL. From [go bindings for OpenGL](https://github.com/go-gl/gl) it seems there are three ways to install it:

```
go get -u github.com/go-gl/gl/v{3.2,3.3,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5,4.6}-{core,compatibility}/gl
go get -u github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.1/gles2
go get -u github.com/go-gl/gl/v2.1/gl
```

Which of these commands do I need to use? I am working on `Windows7` and using `go version go1.12.9 windows/386`

Thanks for your help.

***Edit:***

I tried following commands:

```
go get -u github.com/go-gl/gl/v2.1/gl
go get -u github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.6-core/gl
go get -u github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.6-compatibility/gl
```

They all install all right but same error is persisting on trying to run built executable.

I also tried gles2 but it does not install rather gives following error:

```
I:\>go get -u github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.1/gles2
# github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.1/gles2
C:\Users\ABCD\go\src\github.com\go-gl\gl\v3.1\gles2\package.go:38:11: fatal error: KHR/khrplatform.h: No such file or directory
 // #include <KHR/khrplatform.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Hi, I am not a Go developer, but typically opengl libraries come from your graphics card drivers. If it is failing to run, Chances are your drivers/hardware is too old to load the requested OpenGL context. And looks like Fyne needs OpenGL 3.2-core. ( https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/blob/master/internal/driver/gl/window.go#L17 ). Try updating your graphics card drivers, or try using the software renderer using mesa: https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag .

Comment: So I should put Mesa3D dll in same folder and try to run the built executable again?

Comment: Ok. It did not work after installing `3.2-core` version but it worked after `opengl32.dll` ! You may enter this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I would like to fix Fyne so that others do not run into this problem- what hardware / operating system version are you using?

Comment: I am working on `Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3220 CPU @3.30GHz 3.30GHz` with `Windows7 64bit` with `4Gb RAM`

Comment: @ajwillia.ms : Could you comment on this question for which I have received not even one comment let alone answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57630341/gui-not-running-not-finding-entry-point-in-dll

Comment: Do you know what graphics card and driver are installed?

Comment: I have NVIDIA GeForce 210 card installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OpenGL libraries typically come from your graphics card drivers, and looks like Fyne-io needs fairly new Graphics Card Drivers. (<s>It uses OpenGL 3.2 which was released around 2009</s> It uses OpenGL 2.0). So you can try to:

- Use a Software Implementation of OpenGL using the Mesa project, which should be "good enough" for most desktop apps use cases - more details here: https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag

Or

- Update your Graphics Card drivers - If they are available for your hardware, to get GPU accelerated OpenGL. Definitely try this this if you are planning on making a graphics intensive application).

**Edit:** Updated the version of the OpenGL context Fyne uses

Comment: It actually only requires 2.0 - the 3.2 is just the version of the Go bindings. This older version was released in 2004, so I’m really interested in what sort of computer didn’t have it available?

Comment: Actually, it builds and runs all right but font on label and button is very small. What can be done to increase size of font.

Comment: @ajwillia.ms : I have posted above comment as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645973/increasing-default-font-size-of-this-simple-go-gui-application

Comment: I just tested this because I had problems with Win 7 under Virtualbox: it works fine when I either use the injector or drop the DLL next to my exe. @andy.xyz is it possible to create a single exe that contains and uses the DLL ? Do you happen to know this ?

Comment: We don't want to include software-only rendering in Fyne, it is so much slower than the code path that normally executes that it could be problematic. The root of the issue is, I think, that virtualBox has no OpenGL driver and so you need to install one, such as this DLL.

If you want to re-package the windows binary to ship a software renderer for your own uses that may be possible, but I don't know the details.